# hierarchical data best practice in relational database

Tags: mysql

we have 1 table that also references itself in `parent_id`

table high level structure: (let's assume that data is above 1M rows)

```
 category_table
 id int
 name varchar
 parent_id int
```

the goal is to get the categories with their parent category names.

i have 2 approach in mind

A) do a select query and join `category_table` to itself

```
 select a.*, b.name from category_table a left join category_table b on a.id=b.parent_id
```

B) add another column for the parent name = `parent_name`

```
  category_table
  id int
  name varchar
  parent_id int
  parent_name varchar
```

then do a single select statement to fetch the data

```
 select * from category_table
```

my worries are,
A is what i think the right approach is but when fetching data it may be slow.
B is faster than A however i will introduce a redundant column and will be a challenge when i update the real parent name

would like to know your thoughts on which one is the best way to approach this and if you have any other suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with all denormalization decisions, it boils down to two things:

1. How important is it to optimize the query performance? If the query with the JOIN provides satisfactory performance, then use that, because the database will enforce its own data integrity to prevent update anomalies. However, if the difference is performance is great enough that you definitely cannot satisfy your performance objective if you use the JOIN solution, then you must use the denormalization.
2. Do you have a robust plan for accounting for the data anomalies? You correctly identified that you could have a challenge if category names change, because you need to remember to update them in multiple rows. How confident are you that you can write the code perfectly to do that? Alternatively, do you have a plan for detecting and correcting anomalies that occur if updates fail to update the category name in all necessary places? Do the updates and the correction code account for concurrent updates?